# Find duplicates of a particular file

Tags: windows-7, deduplication

I downloaded an icon library from some website and I used several of the icons in a project. Now I need to find another icon from the library, but I can not find the library on my computer.
Because I copied several files out of the library, I know that I have duplicates on the drive, so I should be able to run a duplicate detector and find the rest of the library.
I have experience with several duplicate detecting programs, but they all scan the entire drive and find all duplicates (which can take hours).
Is there a good program out there that can find duplicates of selected files only?

I am using Windows 7 (Ultimate, although that should not matter).

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: Using Windows 7 (Ultimate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Fast Duplicate File Finder:](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder-About.htm)

> Fast Duplicate File Finder FREEWARE will help you find fast all
>   duplicate files in a folder and its sub folders. The application will
>   compare the content of your files so it will find duplicates even if
>   they are using different file names. The Professional version can even
>   find similar files regardless of their file types. It will analyze the
>   content of the files in order to find similar files and not just file
>   attributes like name and size as the standard duplicate file finders
>   do.

The duplicate remover has the following features:

- Find DUPLICATE files or find SIMILAR files in user specified folders, hard drives, computers or entire networks
- Fast binary comparison algorithm
- Internal preview supporting images, videos, music, text and binary files
- Older or smaller files can be automatically marked for deletion
- Duplicate files can be moved to Recycle Bin, custom folder or deleted permanently
- Support for all kinds of removable media - usb drives, diskettes etc.
- Has intuitive interface and rich documentation
- Process priority settings that will let the application scan in your computers IDLE time
- Protection for system files and folders that will prevent damages to your system files
- Automatically locate duplicate files in Windows Explorer
- Open file with associated program
- Powerful filter and exclude from auto-check options
- Powerful Quick Check/Uncheck dialog
- Multi-language file system support

Comment: Does not find a duplicate of one specific file, but because I have a general idea of the right place, this did run faster than a standard duplicate detector. Unfortunately, it did not find the first file I tried at all (a PNG image). It did find other duplicates.

Comment: Many of the options in that list above that are actually useful are only available in the Pro version.  Still, the free version was a useful starting point.