# How to check if two files are identical, within a Windows shell script?

Tags: windows, shell-script, file-comparison

I am writing a shell script using the Windows NT(ish) shell scripting language.  (My computer has Windows 10.)  I want to check if two text files are identical.  If the files are identical, I want my script to do one thing.  If the files are not identical, I want my script to do something else.  The script should not pause to ask for manual entry of more data.

The "Similar Questions" list has questions about Macintosh and bash shell scripts. It also has an answer about running `fc` or `comp` from the command line, which provide a verbose output.  Unfortunately, <s>`fc` does not return a result to `%errorlevel%`, and</s> `comp` asks for manual data entry instead of simply exiting.

I have a copy of Tim Hill's book on Windows NT shell scripting.  Page 216 has the following line of code, where `%D1%` and `%D2%` are directories, but I do not know how to modify it to work on just a single pair of files:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('fc /b %D1%\*.* %D2%\*.* ^| find /v "Comparing" ^| find /v "FC: no*"') do (set /a ERRORS+=1) & (echo %%I)
```

Comment: Is PowersShell an option? Because if it is, you might find [Get-FileHash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash) useful. I once wrote a script that removes the duplicate files from the second path; however, one can easily replace that with another command: https://superuser.com/questions/1219008/find-and-delete-duplicated-files-in-different-disks-and-directories/1219012#1219012

Comment: @flolilolilo -- No, the rest of the script is already in the Windows NT shell scripting language.  Is there a trivial way to wrap a PowerShell script to be called by a Windows NT shell script?

Comment: What happens if you take Mr Hill's line and replace `%D1%\*.*` and `%D2%\*.*` with single file names, or variables representing single file names?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin -- Running `fc /b a.txt b.txt | find /v "Comparing" | find /v "FC: no*"` from the command line does not produce a simple yes/no answer, but does pollute stdout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
fc /b file1 file2 > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto files_differ
[files are the same, do something here]

:files_differ
[files are not the same, do something here]
```

An `errorlevel` of `1` is returned if the files are NOT identical.

An `errorlevel` of `2` means that one of the files is missing.

`> nul` is used to hide the output of the command

Alternatively, you can use [Busybox](https://frippery.org/busybox/) for Windows and check if the file hashes are the same.

Comment: `> nul` only eats stdout; it still pollutes stderr when a file is missing.  `1> nul 2> nul` eats both stdout and stderr.

Comment: @Jasper Indeed!

Comment: #@Jasper Or `>nul 2>&1` :)